# Android - Back Button With Multiple WebViews

Tags: android, webview

I'm trying to make it so that when the back button on the person's phone is pressed and the focused webview cannot go back, then, super.onBackPressed(); is called and the app minimizes.

```
public void onBackPressed(){

    if 
    (WV1.isFocused() && WV1.canGoBack()) {
        WV1.goBack();
    }

    else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
    if (WV2.isFocused() && WV2.canGoBack()) {
        WV2.goBack();
    }

    else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

That's what I'm trying now but it just minimizes the app, if the webview can go back or not.

Thank you for any help in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens is that you app is performing both actions, making the webview go back AND calling `super`, which will minimize your app.
That happens because both webviews can't be focused at the same time, therefore either `if-else` statement will enter the `else` case, and call `super`.

This code may solve your problem:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (WV1.isFocused() && WV1.canGoBack()) {
        WV1.goBack();
    }
    else if (WV2.isFocused() && WV2.canGoBack()) {
        WV2.goBack();
    }
    else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I cannot believe I didn't think of that... Worked like a charm! :)